# CSS Flex - get div into the other div/box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

---

I am having the following Issue:
I got a Website with a quite large **DIV element**, in which there is a **img** (sullsize).
As on the main index site, I want to have the "Site Title" called Palette within the **DIV**, not on the outside. Whenevery I try to do it with the **Flex CSS**, the Image will not go to the end (fill the element).

### **"My Team Site"**

So my current issue is, I can't get the Palette Text into the item, and also I will be listing Photos and Jobdescriptions for the individuals, each has it's own **flexbox**, so it will behave right.
As said, I can't get them to be **within the box**.

**The easyest way is if you look at my (Sample) Website:**

- [LINK](http://maler1.calmarsolutions.ch/palette.html) (it should look like on the main site. Maybee even with
  Flex, instead of old-fashioned way)
- Dashed Orange: Text Box
- Dashed Red: Future Team Div (1 per Person)

*This is the basic HTML and a part (ONLY A PART!) of the CSS, look at the Rest on the Website:*

```css
  .content_item .content_title {
            position: relative;
            overflow: visible;
            display: inline-block;
            height: 100%;
            width: 45%;
            float: right;

            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 1;
        }

        .content_item h2 {
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 0;
            padding-left: 20px;
            width: 100px;

            flex-grow: 1;
            flex-shrink: 1;

            color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .9);
            white-space: nowrap;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-size: 5em;

            -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
            transform: rotate(270deg);
        }
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="site_palette">

            <div class="header_div">
                <h1 class="header_title">Schwarz & Torf Maler AG</h1>
                <h3 class="header_subtitle">Wir Malen wo andere nur zuschauen</h3>
            </div>

        <div class="flex_container">
            <a href="index.html">
                    <div class="content_item shadowbox_red">
                        <img src="http://maler1.calmarsolutions.ch/images/center_3.jpg" />
                        <div class="team_section">
                            <div class="team_part">
                                <img src="">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="content_title">
                            <h2>Palette</h2>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </a>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Running the code you provided, the Palette Text does go into the item. Perhaps the issue is with some other pieces of code that you didn't provide.

Comment: @MosesDavidowitz Exactly. That is why I have a link to the Website above. Can't figure it out :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flex container is `.content_item`.

This container has three children (flex items):

- `img`
- `div.team_section`
- `div.content_title`

Since these are three *in-flow* flex items, they respect each other's space and don't overlap.

The text you want to layer over the image is in an absolutely-positioned `h2`, which is a child of relatively-positioned `.content-title`.

What you need to do is add `position: relative` to the primary container, then apply `position: absolute` the non-image flex items.

Add this to your code:

```
.site_palette .content_item {
    position: relative;
}
.team_section {
   position: absolute;
}

/* adjustment below may be unnecessary */
.content_item .content_title {
   /* position: relative; */
   position: absolute;
   right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.site_palette .content_item {
    max-width: 70vw;
    position: absolute;
}

.team_section {
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Locate the following code in your css:

```
.team_section {
   display: flex;
}
```

And change it to:

```
.team_section {
   display: none;
}
```